# Search imported csv for select text and make dictionary of results

Tags: python, regex, csv, dictionary

I have a large data set of CT chest exams I need to import into a dictionary using python, search for select text, then output the selected rows as a csv.

Here is my code so far:

```
nodule_4mm = '4 mm'
result = {}
csv_columns = ['Rank','Accession1','MRN1','Textbox2',
           'Textbox47','Textbox43','Textbox45',
           'ReadBy','SignedBy','Addendum1','ReadDate',
           'SignedDate','Textbox49','Result','Impression']

rootdir = '/Users/davidbmccoy/Documents/Chest_Nodule_DataMine';
file = 'NodulesEdited.csv'

path = rootdir
os.chdir(path)

reader = csv.DictReader(open(file, 'rU'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.iteritems():
        if re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(nodule_4mm), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search:
            result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print result
```

There are several things wrong with this. If '4 mm' is found in row I need it to go to result only once.  After all of the rows with '4 mm' are in result I need result to be exported as a csv.

Any help would be great, sorry if the formatting is off here. But really, any help would be great!

Comment: So you want to create a csv that has only rows where a '4 mm' is contained in the row?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I think that your only lack is a "break" statement right after the append command.  In other words, if you've found '4 mm' already, break the inner loop, so that you go to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the following:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(input_file, 'rU'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
nodule_size = "([0-4] mm)"

with open (output_file_name, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')
    w.writerow(csv_columns)

    for row in reader:
        if re.search(nodule_size,row['Result']) or re.search(nodule_size,row['Impression']):

            w.writerow([row['Rank'],row['Accession1'], row['MRN1'],row['Textbox2'],row['Textbox47'],
                        row['Textbox43'],row['Textbox45'],row['ReadBy'],row['SignedBy'],
                        row['Addendum1'],row['ReadDate'],row['SignedDate'],
                        row['Textbox49'],row['Result'],row['Impression']])
```

Hope that helps someone else! Cheers and thanks for the suggestions.